# 2-Step Verification code not automatically detected on Android

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-s-5, 2-step-verification

I just got a new Samsung Galaxy S5 and had it activated on my carrier. I opened the Play Store and entered my gmail and password. Next it says:

> 2-Step Verification
>
> Verifying your phone automatically via text message
>
> This may take a few minutes...
>
> Having trouble?

Within seconds I received the 2-step verification SMS text message, but the app does not seem to be responding to it. A simple bar animation shows that it's still waiting.

I tried following the "Having trouble?" link but the only option there is to resend the message. I've tried that a few times and received the verification code again, but it still would not continue.

The 2-step verification process worked fine on my previous phone (S3), but I used to enter the code manually.

The phone is running Android 5.0. This problem occurs whether I'm on WiFi or Network.

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I found a partial solution to my question:

I was unable to use the 2-step verification using SMS message. I went to my google account settings and changed to Voice Call instead of SMS

Instructions:

1. Go to https://myaccount.google.com/ (make sure it's logged in to your desired account)
2. Select "Sign-in and security"
3. Edit the 2-Step Verification (pencil symbol)
4. Click on "Text message" in "Codes sent via:   Text message"
5. Change to "Voice Call"
6. Save

Then try signing in to the app again. This time it'll ask for you to enter the code manually which should arrive after a few seconds (or minutes) via a phone call. You can then change the settings back to "Text message (SMS)" if you like.

Hope this helps others.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on my Galaxy S5.  I had a different messaging app as my default.  When I reverted my default back to the stock messaging app, it was able to automatically verify via text.

Comment: To revert back to stock, I opened Hangouts, went to Settings | SMS | Set Hangouts as default SMS app

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the [Google Authenticator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.authenticator2) app for two-factor authentication. It can't be "detected" like a text message, meaning  you have to manually input the code.